# ConTeXt xtables never \def'ed

Tags: context, extreme-tables

I am new of ConTeXt.

I want to use xtables but I get an error: \startxtable was never \def'ed.

Am I forgetting some very basic thing?

```
\starttext
\startxtable[width=4cm]
  \startxrow
     \startxcell one \stopxcell
     \startxcell two \stopxcell
   \stopxrow
   \startxrow
      \startxcell alpha \stopxcell
      \startxcell beta  \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
\stopxtable
\stoptext
```

Comment: It also works with the latest ConTeXt suite (2014.03.20 16:59).

Comment: Indeed, my version it pretty old. I'll try to update it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with the ConTeXt version which comes with TeXLive 2013 `ConTeXt ver: 2013.05.28 00:36 MKIV current fmt: 2014.1.3`